# Estimating time of existence of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to estimate the maximum interval of the form $(0, \omega)$ of existence of solutions to the equation:
$$u'(t) = u^3 + (2+\sin(t))u^5 = f(t,u)$$
$$u(0)=1$$

We notice the solution satisfies $u(t) > 0$ for all $t > 0$, since $u(0) > 0$ and $u'(t) \geq 0$. Since $f(t,u) \geq u^5 = g(t,u)$ we can bound our solutions from below by the function:
$$ z(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1-4t}}$$
which is the solution to the IVP $$z'(t) = z^5$$ $$z(0)=1$$

Since $z$ blows up at time $t=\frac{1}{4}$, then $\omega \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

Mi question is: **Are there better bounds available with elementary methods (no software solutions)?** We can for sure get more precise bounds for $f$, for example, $f(t,u) \geq u^3 + u^5$, but the associated equation is significantly more difficult to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pole of the bound is at $t=4$. Integrating $u'/u^5\ge 2+\sin(t)$ should give immediately a better bound.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, there was an error in the statement. The pole is actually at $t= \frac{1}{4}$, as my solution said.

But you are right $u^5 ( 2+\sin(t))$ is easy to integrate and gives a better bound. Thank you very much!